# How do I clear the values in a string during each loop iteration?

Tags: c++

I want to append a different value of b to my original number, but refresh after one iteration of the loop (after each cout) the original num value and the decVal value back to an empty string and 0. How would I do that? For example, instead of returning 001 = 1, 011 = 3, I get 001 = 1, 001011 = 4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int n, decVal;
    int i = 7;
    string num, b, originalnum; 
    cin >> n;
    for (x = 0; x < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> num;
        cin.get(b);
        cin.ignore();
        originalnum += b;
        decVal += atoi(&b) * pow(2, i);
        i -= 1;
        cout << "The decimal equivalent of " << originalnum << " = " << decVal << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare the string variable that you want reset inside the loop instead of before the loop. One key concept in c++ is to limit the scope of variables to the minimum needed scope.

Comment: There's a [clear function](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/clear/) but @drescherjm 's suggestion is cleaner.

Comment: This code wouldn't compile. You have missing semicolons in a few places, and a type mismatch in `atoi(&b)`.

Comment: Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`). See: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: don't use `pow(2, i)`. Use `1 << i` instead

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you want to be able to repeat entering the number of bits and outputting the string holding the representation of the bits and the decimal value. You want all variables to be reset between different iterations for `decVal`. To make that possible, along with fixing a few errors, you simply need to wrap what you are currently doing in another loop so that for each iteration of the outer loop, you process all the bits you like an come up with a final `decVal` to output.

Before looking at a solution, as mentioned in the comment above, `void main()` is only valid for a *freestanding environment* (e.g. no Operating System, like a microcontroller, etc..) Otherwise, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`). See [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

While convenient, you will also want to read [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696) and so you understand the difference between `'\n'` and `std::endl`, go ahead a look at [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

One thing you must always do with EVERY input is to validate it succeeds by checking the stream-state after the attempted input and BEFORE you use the variable filled by the input. If a matching failure occurs, `failbit` will be set and you must clear the error bit before attempting your next input. You can handle the error any way you like, from either ending the program, or by clearing the error bit and removing the characters that caused the problem with `.ignore()` (examples of both are shown below). Essentially, at minimum, you need something like:

```
        if (!(std::cin >> n)) {             /* validate EVERY user input */
            std::cerr << "invalid unsigned input -- exiting.\n";
            return 1;
        }
```

(**note:** instead of just calling `.ignore()`, you should use its full and proper invocation removing up to the maximum number of values for any particular circumstance. When reading from a file-steam, that is: `std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`)

Now for your program setup, you can essentially just use a continual loop around code similar to what you have and just provide a mechanism to exit the outer loop when the user is done entering values. For example, using a simple `while(1)` loop and having the user enter anything other than a valid number for `n`, you could do:

```
    while (1) {                             /* outer loop - loop continually */
        size_t n;                           /* declare variables within loop */
        uint32_t decVal = 0;
        std::string originalnum {}; 
        
        std::cout << "\nenter no. of bits ('q' to quit): ";
        if (!(std::cin >> n)) {             /* validate EVERY user input */
            std::cerr << "invalid unsigned input -- exiting.\n";
            return 1;
        }
```

Note: all variables are declared inside the loop, so for each iteration, the variables are declared and initialized each time. Above the user is told to press `'q'` to quit -- but can enter anything that is not a valid number to exit. That will simply exit the program returning control to the calling process.

Look at your code, there really isn't any need for the `pow()` function to compute `decVal` from the user's entry of `0`'s and `1`'s. Instead, you can simply declare `decVal` as an `unsigned` value (an exact with `uint32_t` is used below) and simply use *Left-Shift* to shift each input by the current loop counter number of bits.

Using the left-shift described above to compute `decVal` (ensuring `decVal` is initialized to zero when declared), and adding the user inputs to the front of the string to preserve LSB first order, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <climits>

int main (void)
{
    while (1) {                             /* outer loop - loop continually */
        size_t n;                           /* declare variables within loop */
        uint32_t decVal = 0;
        std::string originalnum {}; 
        
        std::cout << "\nenter no. of bits ('q' to quit): ";
        if (!(std::cin >> n)) {             /* validate EVERY user input */
            std::cerr << "invalid unsigned input -- exiting.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (n > sizeof (uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT) { /* validate EVERY value in range */
            std::cerr << "  error: n exceeds no. of bits avaialble.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n;) {        /* inner loop, process bits */
            uint32_t bit;
            std::cout << " bit" << std::setw(2) << i << ": ";
            if (!(std::cin >> bit) || bit > 1) {
                std::cerr << "  error: invalid bit input.\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                continue;
            }
            decVal += bit << i;                     /* no need for pow(), left-shift */
            originalnum.insert(0, 1, bit + '0');    /* build originalnum each iteration */
            i++;                                    /* increemnt on good input */
        }
        /* result */
        std:: cout << "The decimal equivalent of " << originalnum << 
                        " = " << decVal << '\n';
    }
}
```

(**note:** [Numeric limits -- cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) shows the header files needed for each limit used)

**Example Use/Output**

Below is input and output similar to what you show, but with prompts added to guide the user, and error handling implemented to ensure only valid `0`'s and `1`'s are taken as input:

```
$ ./bin/decval

enter no. of bits ('q' to quit): 3
 bit 0: 1
 bit 1: 1
 bit 2: 0
The decimal equivalent of 011 = 3

enter no. of bits ('q' to quit): 3
 bit 0: 1
 bit 1: 0
 bit 2: 0
The decimal equivalent of 001 = 1

enter no. of bits ('q' to quit): 3
 bit 0: 1
 bit 1: 0
 bit 2: pickles
  error: invalid bit input.
 bit 2: 1
The decimal equivalent of 101 = 5

enter no. of bits ('q' to quit): q
invalid unsigned input -- exiting.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions or if I misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score -1):

Just clear the string after the

```
cout << ... << endl;
```

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int n, decVal;
    int i = 7;
    string num, b, originalnum; 
    cin >> n;
    for (x = 0; x < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> num;
        cin.get(b);
        cin.ignore();
        originalnum += b
        decVal += atoi(&b) * pow(2, i);
        i -= 1
        cout << "The decimal equivalent of " << originalnum << " = " << decVal << endl;
        originalnum = "";
        n = 0;
    }
}
```